# Why is this Targaryen not immune to fire?

Tags: game-of-thrones

We know that Jon Snow is the son of Rhaegar Targaryen and has Targaryen blood running in his veins. Also, we have earlier seen that he is not immune to fire, unlike his aunt Daenerys. Why is this so? Is he not a true dragon?

Comment: AFAIK Darnerys is the only targaryen to be fireproof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-Jon-Snow-be-a-Targaryen-if-he-burnt-his-hand-in-the-book-Game-of-Thrones-while-saving-the-commander-from-the-white-walker)

Targaryens are not immune to fire. What happened to Daenerys on the funeral pyre was a one-time event (or rather two-time - recall episode 4 of season 6), according to the author, who's discussed it at fan events. So Daenerys herself isn't immune to fire either (and the thing with the eggs, where she isn't burned, IS NOT in the books). Plenty of Targaryens have been killed because of fire or extreme heat: Viserys, Aerion Brightflame who drank wildfire, Aegon V and his son Prince Duncan who died in a fire at Summerhall, and Rhaenyra Targaryen who was fed to her brother's dragon. So it's not that Viserys should have been fireproof, it's that NO Targ is inherently fireproof.

Comment: This question seems to be about the show, though, where Daenerys is immune to fire. Perhaps you could give a show answer?

Comment: Well, there isn't much canon regarding this to go by in the show. Having said that, I will dig around a bit to see if I can find some more info.

Comment: You forgot to mention the instance of Daenerys bathing in scolding hot water and not minding it at all (episode 1 of the show I believe) - which, of course, foreshadowed the later survival of the pyre. So it's safe to say that these were not accidents - in the show at least, Daenerys is indeed immune to at least pyre levels of heat. It doesn't demonstrate, though, that she is immune to wildfire and dragonfire, which are presumably hotter.

Comment: Not to mention, her confidence in deliberately orchestrating the burning events goes to show she has quite a high confidence in her fire immunity, suggesting she had similar occurrences and possibly experiments that are not shown on-screen.

Comment: For Rhaenyra, it could be possible she wasn't actually burned, just eaten.